# Can we use auto with class member initializers in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In C++ we have class member initializers, yet I cannot seem to use auto/static type deduction for non-static members.

```
struct Foo {
    auto bar = []() { return 1; };
    auto baz = "test";
};
```

That won't work (at least on clang: Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24)).

Is this just a compiler bug, or does the standard not require this to be supported (and if so, why can't it be)?

Comment: You are right, thanks (I did search, not sure how I missed this!) closing.

Comment: Note that for the first case, an [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) would work (on the off-chance that was your motivation for the question).

Comment: That was my motivation for the question, and you are right, using std::function does work.  I wanted to compare using std::function to using lambda's type directly, which is how this problem arose.